# Incorrect resolution detected while designing a site

Tags: html, web, retina

I must be super behind or just super new to the retina displays on MBPs but designing a site for it is just odd. I get that the resolution is 2560x1600 on this 13 inch MBP. So why is chrome only seeing 1296px wide? I feel really silly for even asking but I couldn't ask google the right question to get any real solutions to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The Macbook Pro is one of the devices with a [pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) of 2. This means it packs 2560  (2560 = 1280 * 2) by 1600 (800 * 2) of screen on a 1280x800 physical screen.

Read this Wikipedia list of [displays by pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density).

When designing a site, look at media queries to handle these differences. Here is [one relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030041/media-query-pixel-density-and-max-width-together).

Comment: Yeah found some other info on it like needing to right media query like

`@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 
  
  /* Retina-specific stuff here */

}`