# Hiding content from mobile email clients and displaying on desktops (that don't read media queries)?

Tags: css, email, media-queries, html-email

I'm trying to find as reliable a method as possible to hide content from mobile email clients.

Ideally the solution will hide content by default from devices that don't read media queries, but display on desktop clients that also don't read media queries.

For now I'm using code derived from another post to hide the content and then I use a media query to turn it back on. I've seen a lot of [reverse posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013670/gmail-is-ignoring-displaynone/13361310#13361310) here with solutions for hiding content on the desktop, which helped.

The issues with my current solution are:

- On Gmail desktop content isn't showing even though the "display: block !important" in the query has the !important declaration
- This doesn't work for Outlook 2003 or below because they don't read media queries
- Doesn't work on Yahoo and AOL Mail on desktop because I believe they don't read media queries

Wrapper div to hide content on mobile:

```
  <div class="desktop" style="width:0; overflow:hidden;float:left; display:none">
```

Current media query override to turn content on for tablets,desktops:

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)  {

```
 .desktop {
  display : block !important;
  width : auto !important;
  overflow : visible !important;
  float : none !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail doesn't support the style tag, so media queries will not work. Same goes for [all of these clients](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2012/10/responsive-email-support/) (you mentioned a few of them).

There are a few tricks where you can target some specific clients by using CSS that is not supported in others, (plus [mso tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861336/outlook-2007-to-2013-displaying-device-media-queries/16861923#16861923) for Outlook). For desktop vs mobile, you're pretty much stuck with media queries, which are not fully supported themselves.

As you've linked in the question, you can try combinations of `max-width` and/or `min-width` media queries. You [could also try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030041/media-query-pixel-density-and-max-width-together) `device-pixel-ratio` in your media queries to isolate devices. That is pretty much all you have to play with unless you want to use floats or fluid layouts.

CSS `display` is not supposed to be supported in Gmail according to [CM's CSS support chart](http://campaignmonitor.cachefly.net/assets/files/css/campaign-monitor-guide-to-css-in-email-jan-2013.pdf?ver=1252) (full pdf), but if it is in fact hiding your content, you won't be able to override the inline declaration due to the lack of style tag support. This issue would have been there with the other non style tag supported clients anyway...

Not really a solution, but I hope this clarifies things a bit.