# @media queries not working

Tags: html, media-queries, html-email

```
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 td[class="body-copy"] {
     font-size:36px !important
}
</style>

<td class="body-copy" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; font-   
size:12px">Hi everyone</td>
```

Hi - the media simple query ( truncated above) in my email doesn't work at all when tested on an iPhone. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Version of iPhone? And why do you have a `td` tag without a `table`...?

Comment: Hi - it's an iPhone 5 - I've just extracted the element that I applied the class to, there is a table it sits in.

Comment: I don't have a device to test with, but just use `max-width` instead...? [Basic Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/82YS3/)

Comment: Have you tried applying '-webkit-text-size-adjust:none' to the body of your email? The second possibility is that another CSS rule conflicts with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the media="screen"

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0, minimum-scale=1">

<style type="text/css" media="screen" >
    @media all and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 50px) {
```

Also try **max-width** instead of **max-device-width** to see the result in your PC

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the input but sadly no change - doesn't even scale in the browser if I drag the window smaller.

Comment: But I have just noticed in the Dreamweaver preview window it does scale if I drag the window smaller...

Comment: Thanks Khaled - but it still doesn't work on the device

Comment: Hi Khaled, no change. I think I'm going to start from scratch, there has to be an error in my code somewhere for this not to work. Thanks for all your help though.

Comment: No problem I think you need to also change the condition for your media tag **@media all** and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 50px){}

Answer (score 0):

It is because the iPhone 5 has a higher resolution (1136 x 640 pixels). Try increasing your max width.

Also, `max-width` works better than `max-device-width` as I believe it ignores pixel density.

If you want to target high resolution devices, without triggering screen (limiting it to pixel dense screens), you could also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030041/media-query-pixel-density-and-max-width-together). Not sure if it works for html email, so let me know how it goes.

Comment: Try losing the `[class=""]` in your media query declarations and see if it works. This will help pinpoint the cause. Do any media queries work at all? Also, are you using a corporate email address? Sometimes corporate filters can strip them.

Comment: Hi John - that actually worked, but only in the browser. If I drag the browser window smaller it works - but it sill doesn't work in the email!

Comment: Are you using `max-width` now? Switch back to `max-device-width`. Play with the width values until it triggers. Start ridiculously huge to make sure it works at all. If a generous range doesn't work, there is something getting stripped by your server, or the way you are sending it.

Comment: Hi - thanks.. I tried max-device-width but it stopped working in the browser. Putting it back, it again worked in the browser, responding to the different screen widths but nothing works in IoS mail..

Comment: This is now where I am:

    <style type="text/css" media="screen" >
 @media only screen and (max-width : 480px){
 td[class="body-copy"] {
     font-size:30px !important
    }

    }

With a corresponding element in the body:

    <td class="body-copy" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;   
    color:#FFFFFF; font-size:12px">

Comment: `max-device-width` will not work in the browser, but should work on the iPhone. It triggers off of the device width (accounting for pixel density on retina devices), not the window. If you wanted to stick to just `max-width`, you'd have to increase your media query to be > than 480. Some people test their email in `max-width` before switching it out last minute for devices. If you want to try and have the best of both worlds, you could [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030041/media-query-pixel-density-and-max-width-together). I haven't tested it on emails yet however.

Comment: Hey John - thanks for that - I'm tempted to ask if I could send the html file over and see if you can work out where I'm going wrong..